# cpan problems with 02packages.details.txt.gz

Tags: linux, perl, cpan

I'm getting complaints about 02packages.details.txt.gz when I'm trying to install a package with cpan. The error is "Warning: Your /root/.cpan/sources/modules/02packages.details.txt.gz does not contain a Line-Count header.
"

Apparently, according to cpan, this is not a valid zip file, which it isn't. It's just a web page which I'll paste later. I do not use a proxy and I had five mirrors in my configuration. I've deleted one then the next off the list and I'm still getting the same data back. I have deleted the file and attempted to allow cpan to fetch it again. I have fetched the page with curl and I'm seeing a web page and *not* anything that looks like a gz file.

I have tried "install cpan" from the cpan command line in case I missed an update but that runs into the exact same problem.

Example fetch:

```
curl http://noodle.portalus.net/CPAN/modules/02packages.details.txt.gz
```

Result (parts obsfucated)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript">
function getCookie(c_name) { // Local function for getting a cookie value
    if (document.cookie.length > 0) {
        c_start = document.cookie.indexOf(c_name + "=");
        if (c_start!=-1) {
        c_start=c_start + c_name.length + 1;
        c_end=document.cookie.indexOf(";", c_start);

        if (c_end==-1)
            c_end = document.cookie.length;

        return unescape(document.cookie.substring(c_start,c_end));
        }
    }
    return "";
}
function setCookie(c_name, value, expiredays) { // Local function for setting a value of a cookie
    var exdate = new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate()+expiredays);
    document.cookie = c_name + "=" + escape(value) + ((expiredays==null) ? "" : ";expires=" + exdate.toGMTString()) + ";path=/";
}
function getHostUri() {
    var loc = document.location;
    return loc.toString();
}
setCookie('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXiw_9289NNNNNNNNJAX666', 'MY.IP.ADDRESS.HERE', 10);
try {
    location.reload(true);
} catch (err1) {
    try {
        location.reload();
    } catch (err2) {
        location.href = getHostUri();
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<noscript>This site requires JavaScript and Cookies to be enabled. Please change your browser settings or upgrade your browser.</noscript>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that this is the same as the contents as fetched by cpan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CPAN stands for Comprehensive Perl Archive Network. The network once consisted of a slew of mirrors, but this has been replaced with a transparent Content Delivery Network (CDN).

The once-valuable service offered by the mirrors is therefore no longer needed, so many sites have ceased mirroring CPAN. It appears to be the case for the mirror your `cpan` is configured to use.

A simple configuration change is needed to fix the issue. From within the `cpan` tool, use either

```
o conf init urllist
```

or

```
o conf urllist http://www.cpan.org/
```

The first picks a mirror from the "official" list. There is only one URL in the list: `http://www.cpan.org/`. The second picks that URL directly.

To save the changes, follow up with

```
o conf commit
```

(This may not be necessary for everyone, but there's no harm in always using it.)

---

Example:

```
C:\Users\ikegami>cpan
Loading internal logger. Log::Log4perl recommended for better logging
Unable to get Terminal Size. The Win32 GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo call didn't work. The COLUMNS and LINES environment variables didn't work. at C:\progs\sp5032001001\perl\vendor\lib/Term/ReadLine/readline.pm line 410.

cpan shell -- CPAN exploration and modules installation (v2.28)
Enter 'h' for help.

cpan> o conf init urllist

Now you need to choose your CPAN mirror sites.  You can let me
pick mirrors for you, you can select them from a list or you
can enter them by hand.

Would you like me to automatically choose some CPAN mirror
sites for you? (This means connecting to the Internet) [yes] y

Trying to fetch a mirror list from the Internet
Fetching with LWP:
init/MIRRORED.BY
Fetching with LWP:
init/MIRRORED.BY.gz
Fetching with LWP:
http://www.perl.org/CPAN/MIRRORED.BY

Looking for CPAN mirrors near you (please be patient)
.. done!

New urllist
  http://www.cpan.org/

commit: wrote 'C:\progs\sp5032001001\perl\lib/CPAN/Config.pm'

cpan> quit
Lockfile removed.

C:\Users\ikegami>
```

`commit: wrote` indicates the changes were saved, so I didn't need to use `o conf commit`.

Comment: Well, the mirrors can still do their thing but PAUSE and CPAN infrastructure aren't tracking or publishing a list of them.

Comment: @brian d foy Adjusted wording.

Comment: Also, the latest CPAN.pm (2.29) has a new configuration option, pushy_https, that's true by default and ignores urllist. This would make it appear that mirrors no longer work. https://www.reddit.com/r/perl/comments/sv2uba/cpan_on_an_offline_machine_with_a_file_urllist/

Answer (score 0):

It seems like indeed, one after another of my mirrors was stale. Currently using mirrors.namecheap.com and all looking good.

Comment: Use the www.cpan.org mirror and it will select a good mirror for you. It's a big CDN now so you don't need to choose your own mirror.